# How to intersect mysql lines for a json file in nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, json

I would like to ask you for advice as I don't know which method to use:
For example with this query in Mysql i have this table:

| user_Id | name | age | photo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Zack | 23 | Blob[2.1] |
| 1 | Zack | 23 | Blob[3.3] |
| 1 | Zack | 23 | Blob[1.9] |
| 3 | Amy | 19 | Blob[2.9] |
| 3 | Amy | 19 | Blob[3.3] |

In node js when i transform it in a Json file i have 5 rows, but i want 2 rows with the grouped photos. Example:

```json
{
  "0": {
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "Zack",
    "age": 23,
    "photo": [
      "Blob[2.1]",
      "Blob[3.3]",
      "Blob[1.9]"
    ]
  },
  "1": {
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "Amy",
    "age": 19,
    "photo": [
      "Blob[2.9]",
      "Blob[3.3]"
    ]
  }
}
```

So, do I have to use some function in nodejs or do I have to add something in mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate then photo values

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
`user_Id`, `name`, `age`, JSON_ARRAYAGG(`photo`) as photo
FROM Table1
GROUP BY `user_Id`, `name`, `age`;
```

| user_Id | name | age | photo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Zack | 23 | ["Blob[2.1]", "Blob[3.3]", "Blob[1.9]"] |
| 3 | Amy | 19 | ["Blob[2.9]", "Blob[3.3]"] |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j69CAhjggHzrZcQ1EPhPim/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate row indexes as aggregating photo reference values, and then aggregate the resultant individual objects with keys derived from those indexes such as

```
SELECT JSON_PRETTY( JSON_OBJECTAGG(rn,js) ) AS Result
  FROM ( 
         SELECT @i := @i+1 AS rn,
                JSON_OBJECT(
                            'user_id',
                             user_id,
                            'name',
                             name,
                            'age',
                             age,
                            'photo',
                             JSON_ARRAYAGG(photo)
                            ) AS js
          FROM t
          JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) AS q_iter         
         GROUP BY user_id, name, age
         ORDER BY user_id 
       ) j;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j69CAhjggHzrZcQ1EPhPim/1)</kbd>

Comment: he generates the json in javascript no need to do it in mysql

Comment: @nbk well, what about the link I've edited within your answer which also references the DB ?

Comment: i rarely use https://www.db-fiddle.com so i forget to update, but as you crreted it , thanks for that, it only combines the the trhee blos, so that the result set has only 2 rows as wanted